# How to check in ReportViewer if a report exists to prevent rsItemNotFound?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm loading a report into my ReportViewer 10.0 along these lines:

```
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/My.Report.Folder/DoesNotExist";

// The following call throws a ReportServerException ("...rsItemNotFound...")
var requestedParameters = MyReportViewer.ServerReport.GetParameters();

var filledParameters = GetFilledParameters(requestedParameters);

MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(requestedParameters);
MyReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

This works fine, except when the report does not exist. In that case the `GetParameters()` call will fail with a `ReportServerException` and a message along these lines:

> The item '/My.Report.Folder/DoesNotExist' cannot be found. (rsItemNotFound)

Of course I could use a `try...catch` block here to trap this situation, but I'd rather explicitly check if a report exists. Is there a way to do this using the `ReportViewer` component? Or do I need to hook into the SSRS web services?

I've gone through `MyReportViewer.ServerReport`'s methods and properties but found nothing that seems of use. I've also checked [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832819/419956), but it's not really in the context of the ReportViewer control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm open to other answers, but until then, here's my current workaround:

```
try
{
    var requestedParameters = MyReportViewer.ServerReport.GetParameters();

    var filledParameters = GetFilledParameters(requestedParameters);

    MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(requestedParameters);
    MyReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
}
catch (ReportServerException exception)
{
    if (!exception.Message.Contains("rsItemNotFound"))
    {
        throw;
    }
    // Else... ReportViewer will show "rsItemNotFound" error. 
    // Or you can do something fancy in your app here, I suppose :-)
}
```